# Common mistakes in writing JavaScript with a C# background

Tags: c#, javascript, transition

I've been working on improving my JavaScript code.  I've seen several people write that too many people write JavaScript like another language such as C#.  What common things I picked up in  C# are things I should do differently in JavaScript?

Comment: I think this should be a community wiki on the programmers site

Comment: I'll look into that.  It seems I was unaware of the proper way to add this question.

Comment: A little off topic - there is a [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/JocysComJavaScriptClasses.aspx) about doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an excellent (and award winning) article on JavaScript gotchas here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/javascript-gotchas.aspx

It covers:

- Double-equals
- Global variables
- Constructing built-in types with the 'new' keyword
- Constructing anything else without the 'new' keyword
- parseInt doesn't assume base-10
- typeof operator
- instanceof operator
- The absence of data: null and undefined
- Redefining undefined
- this and inner functions
- No block scope
- String replace
- eval
- with
- Optional semicolons
- The "+" operator both adds and concatenates
- There is no Integer
- NaN

and more ...

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://enterprisejquery.com/category/multipart-series/) blog series by Elisha Manor (How Good C# Habits can Encourage Bad JavaScript Habits):

1. Having Variables & Functions in Global Scope
2. Not Declaring Arrays & Objects Correctly
3. Not Understanding False-y Values
4. Not Testing & Setting Default Values Correctly
5. Using the Wrong Comparison Operators
6. Not Using the for…in Statement Correctly

Answer (score 1):

Trailing commas on an object initializer; fine in C#... not so fine in javascript.